# How to find 'Text' by using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
URL= 'https://modernhousevn.com/collections/new-arrival/products/giuong-ngu-mh-21'
driver.get(URL)
sleep(1)
des = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//strong[text()='Chất liệu :']/.."))).get_attribute('innerText')
print(des)
```

My expected result is ['Khung : Khung Gỗ thông - Vạt giường gỗ thông', 'Da PU hoặc vải bố cao cấp nhập khẩu', 'Mousse : D40/35 theo tiêu chuẩn xuất khẩu']

[image]

Comment: I think you want to run `wait until ` on a separate line and then afterwards run `des = driver.find_element(By.XPATH)`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Located `<p>` contain `'Chất liệu'`, back to parent
2. While tag is not `<p>` and parent's class is not `panel-body`, back to parent
3. Find first `<ul>`, find all `<li>` in the `<ul>`

```
sleep(1)
target = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//strong[contains(text(),'Chất liệu')]/..")
while target.tag_name != 'p' and target.find_element(By.XPATH, "./..").get_attribute("class") != 'panel-body':
    target = target.find_element(By.XPATH, "./..")
des = target.find_elements(By.XPATH, './following-sibling::ul[1]/li')
print([d.text for d in des])
```

output

```
['Khung : Khung Gỗ thông - Vạt giường gỗ thông', 'Da PU hoặc vải bố cao cấp nhập khẩu', 'Mousse : D40/35 theo tiêu chuẩn xuất khẩu ']
```

Comment: Shuo, I have another link ('https://modernhousevn.com/collections/new-arrival/products/bo-ban-an-emma-nau-4-ghe-1'), but I can't get data by your way, please help !

Comment: 404 Page Not Found.

Link maybe wrong or page has been delete.

Comment: you try this link: 'https://modernhousevn.com/collections/new-arrival/products/bo-ban-an-anna-tu-nhien-4-ghe'

Comment: Because there is a `<em>` between `<p>` and `<strong>`, I add a while loop to find `p`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace below lines of code.

```
des = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//strong[text()='Chất liệu :']/.."))).Text;
print(des)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it's not worked !

Comment: You have to use FindElements method to get all webelements Test and use below xpath to get all elements

     //strong[text()='Chất liệu :']/../following-sibling::ul/li

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath to find the text which contains it

(By.XPATH,"//strong[contains(text(),'Chất liệu')]");
hope it will work!